# Spring Batch Remote chuncking

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using SpringBatch that running steps in multi threaded
I need an example how to run/configured spring batch running in remote chunking

example link/example code and how it works?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example [project](https://github.com/opencredo/spring-batch-remote-chunking-example) on github for remote chunking. I can advise "Pro Spring Batch" or "Spring Batch in Action" book. Both book contain a remote chunking example.